# In Replace command, match first word(s) of document only

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using Replace to italicize the first word(s) of each paragraph that are followed by a tab using this wildcard expression:

`^13*^t`

The `^13` finds the start of a new paragraph. I only want to replace the first words of a paragraph if they are followed by a tab, hence the `^t`.

And I'm replacing it with `^&`, and italic formatting applied.

This works for everything except the first paragraph in the document, since it doesn't start with a `^13`, apparently. Is there a way to match only the first word(s) followed by a tab?

I'm putting this into a Macro, so I'm open to using features that are only available in a Macro if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with a VBA macro (which you can assign to a shortcut key), without using find and replace.

NB:  This code also assumes you use the method you described in your earlier 
post re SHIFT and ENTER to start new paragraph for same speaker.

The following code loops through each paragraph, and checks each word - it will italicise each word until it finds a tab character, at which point it moves on to the next paragraph, and repeats the process.

```
Sub italiciseBeforeTab()

    Dim para As Paragraph

    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

        Dim wd As Range

        For Each wd In para.Range.Words

            wd.Font.Italic = True
            If wd = vbTab Then Exit For

        Next wd

    Next para

End Sub
```